# Simulate mouse event on dynamic object jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to simulate mouse event on dynamically created object (menu item)
it works on statically created menu, like this:

```
$("#Help").trigger("mouseenter");
```

but doesn't work on menu, that was created dynamically:

```
$("#wsnmotes").trigger("mouseenter");
```

I know, that it is necessary to create a 'delegate', but can't figure out the syntax. Please, help.
Jan

Comment: Provide more context to your question. How do you bind mouseenter event? When do you try to trigger it? Etc...

Comment: Can u post ur dynamic generated code and trigger event also?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 0):

Can you once confirm if you are using like following

```
$( "body" ).on( "mouseenter", "#wsnmotes", function() {
  //do something
});
```

You should use on so dynamically added elements will be attached events as well.

As you are actually binding your event with parent, which exists always, it does work with dynamically added elements.

Comment: Thanks everyone responding,

Comment: Thanks everyone responding, Your code works, but it is not what I need.  My code is invoked like this:                               $.fn.IMclickhandler = function(data){ 
 //alert('YOU clicked ME: ' + data.key);
       $('#patientboxsend').append("mote IP: "+ client_motes[0] + "\r"); // + "\r" 
       $('#patientboxsend').animate({scrollTop:$('#patientboxsend')[0].scrollHeight - $('#patientboxsend').height()},100);
       $('#Help').trigger('mouseenter'); // works 
       $("#wsnmotes").trigger('mouseenter'); // doesn't work                   
 };

Comment: What I need to do is to do programmatically what the user would do by interacting with dropdown menu with mose (opening submenu) Once again it works on statically created menu items not on dynamically created ones.

Comment: code for dynamic menu (works)                                                               for (i=0; i<client_motes_num; i++){ 
 var motename = client_motes[i];
 var length = motename.length;
 var shortmotename = motename.slice(length-4,length); //":e30a";
 var node_id = shortmotename;

 var n = $("#"+node_id).length;
      if(n===0){
 // append the menu

    $('#wsnmotes > ul').append(
      '<li><a id="'+ node_id +'" name = "'+motename+'" href="#"><i class="fa fa-heartbeat"></i>&nbsp;mote IP:  ' + motename + '</a>' +
        '</li>'
        );
 } else{
  //alert("already exist");
 };

};

Comment: Can anyone help, please?